# How to animate elements of a UIStackView that’s created in a separate function

Tags: swift, uistackview

I'm trying to animate a stackview and its elements upon pressing a UIButton. the problem is that the stackview is created inside a function which is called in viewdidload.

Because the stackview is created inside a function I cannot call it inside the function that manages the animation... I think i'm doing something wrong...

my stackview creation function

```swift
    fileprivate func variableContent() {
            let stackviewButtons = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [registerSerialNumberButton, dothislaterButton])
            stackviewButtons.axis = .vertical
            stackviewButtons.alignment = .fill
            stackviewButtons.spacing = 10

            let stackview = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [registerTitlelabel, registerdescriptionLabel, serialnumberInput, stackviewButtons])
            stackview.axis = .vertical
            stackview.spacing = 20
            stackview.setCustomSpacing(40, after: registerdescriptionLabel)
            stackview.setCustomSpacing(100, after: serialnumberInput)
            view.addSubview(stackview)
            stackview.anchor(top: nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)
            stackview.centerXInSuperview()
            stackview.centerYInSuperview()
        }
```

viewdidload

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        variableContent()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the stackview from your function and keep a reference to it as an instance variable. That way you can reuse it later.

```
class Controller: UIViewController {
    var stackView: UIStackView!
    fileprivate func variableContent() -> UIStackView {
        let stackviewButtons = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [registerSerialNumberButton, dothislaterButton])
        stackviewButtons.axis = .vertical
        stackviewButtons.alignment = .fill
        stackviewButtons.spacing = 10

        let stackview = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [registerTitlelabel, registerdescriptionLabel, serialnumberInput, stackviewButtons])
        stackview.axis = .vertical
        stackview.spacing = 20
        stackview.setCustomSpacing(40, after: registerdescriptionLabel)
        stackview.setCustomSpacing(100, after: serialnumberInput)
        view.addSubview(stackview)
        stackview.anchor(top: nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)
        stackview.centerXInSuperview()
        stackview.centerYInSuperview()
        return stackview
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.stackView = variableContent()
    }
}
```

An other option would be to give it a tag (`stackview.tag = 42`)
 and recover it with `self.view.viewWithTag(42)`

Comment: the tag solution made it possible! It does have to be optional once I call it then correct?

Comment: Yes, `viewWithTag` returns an optional UIView.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marcio's answer, you can also declare the stackView optionally and set it in the function:

```
class Controller: UIViewController {
    var stackview: UIStackView?
    fileprivate func variableContent() {
            let stackviewButtons = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [registerSerialNumberButton, dothislaterButton])
            stackviewButtons.axis = .vertical
            stackviewButtons.alignment = .fill
            stackviewButtons.spacing = 10

            self.stackview = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [registerTitlelabel, registerdescriptionLabel, serialnumberInput, stackviewButtons])
            stackview.axis = .vertical
            stackview.spacing = 20
            stackview.setCustomSpacing(40, after: registerdescriptionLabel)
            stackview.setCustomSpacing(100, after: serialnumberInput)
            view.addSubview(stackview)
            stackview.anchor(top: nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)
            stackview.centerXInSuperview()
            stackview.centerYInSuperview()
    }

    // Whatever your animating function is:
    func animateStackView() {
    guard let stackview = self.stackview else { return }
    // You now have access to your stackView for the rest of this function.
    }
}
```

**Note:** For consistency with your question, I kept the name of the `UIStackView` as `stackview` in the code, but according to Swift naming conventions, you should name variables in camelcase (`stackView`)

Comment: this works to make stackview accesable form the animation function, but i cannot animate the stackview in any way. not via transform or by changing attributes... Would you know how this works? I'm trying to animate the stackview inside a uiview.animate

Comment: @CvEijk what do you mean you cannot animate it? Is there an error when you try to animate it or is it just not animating the way you want it to? As long as the function that animates the stackView is called after the stackView has been set by the variableContent() function, I don’t see why the stackView wouldn’t animate.

Comment: there just no movement

Comment: Can you update the question with your UIView.animate code?